# Despite the existence of relevant indices, PostgreSQL query is slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, indices

I have a table with 3 columns:

- time (timestamptz)
- price (numeric(8,2))
- set_id (int)

The table contains 7.4M records.
I've created an simple index for time and an index for set_id.
I want to run the following query:

```
select * from test_prices where time BETWEEN '2015-06-05 00:00:00+00' and '2020-06-05 00:00:00+00';
```

Depsite my indices, the query takes **2 minutes and 30 seconds.**
See explain analze stats: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ZwSH

GCP postgres DB has the following stats:

[image]

What do I miss here? Why is this query so slow and how can I improve?

Comment: Predicate selectivity is about 50% (roughly every second row should be returned), so index will not improve query performance as the DBMS have to read index records and then corresponding table records. Thus it will be nearly the same as to read entire table

Answer (score 1):

According to your explain plan, the row is returning 1.6 million rows out of 4.5 million.  That means that a significant portion of rows are being returned.

Postgres wisely decides that a full table scan is more efficient than using an index, because there is a good chance that all the data pages will need to be read anyway.

It is surprising that you are reporting 00:02:30 for the query.  The explain is saying that the query completes in about 1.4 seconds -- which seems reasonable.

I suspect that the elapsed time is caused by the volume of data being returned (perhaps the rows are very wide), a slow network connection to the database, or contention on the database/server.

Comment: To isolate the issue, I made the query on a superfast server. It still took 6-7 seconds.
The columns are also not very wide. My postgres DB is hosted on GCP and I just attached the stats of that instance. Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your query selects two thirds of the table. A sequential scan is the most efficient way to process such a query.

Your query executes in under 2 seconds. It must be your client that takes a long time to render the query result (pgAdmin is infamous for that). Use a different client.

Comment: Didn't know that pgAdmin could cause such delays. However, I tried directly through psql and the query still took 2 mins.. That would support the hypothesis Gordon made, that my internet speed / connection is the problem. Do you agree?

Comment: That may well be.